# How to find my drafts (Documentation)

Tags: discussion, support, documentation

I searched a lot for my drafts in the new functionality of Stack Overflow.

Where I can find them?

Comment: Does anyone know where I can find *all* my drafts, regardless of tag? **EDIT:** nevermind, found [this answer](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/329428/1667004)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After search of my drafts, I finally found them. I want to share with you how I did that; maybe anyone lost his way, so it is easy. Just follow these steps:

1. https://stackoverflow.com/documentation
2. Tag of your draft: https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/java/topics
3. Dashboard: https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/java

On the right, you can find your drafts.